# Google hangout Application configuration giving error for Application URL

Tags: xml, google-api, google-apps, google-hangouts

I am following instruction for creating application from getting-started(https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started) document but while setting application url for Google hangout Application configuration in google console, I am getting always same error 'The user request is invalid. Please check your URL and try again.'

I have tried google default xml(https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/getting-started) file url for Application URL which is given in same document but still not able to save it's configuration with this url.

I am using correct xml file but still facing Application URL issue? .. Is anyone have any idea for saving  Google hangout Application configuration in google api console

[image]

Comment: is there a space in the front or the back of the url?

Comment: No space there, I used that sample url in correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem. Don't know correct solution. But filling all the three Support url's with dummy values. It saved successfully.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, if you open the Network tab in Chrome's dev console you can inspect the JSON response for more helpful info. You should see a message in there detailing the exact problem with the form submission.

Bravo Google for shoving us on to your lovely new Developer Console that clearly doesn't work properly.